# Mixed Remote/Local Query in Apollo Client very slow

Tags: react-native, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I have a problem with a Query inside Apollo Client, the remote API is GraphQL and the client app is React Native. 
But the problem is that this Query has a @client field inside, when i use this query with @client, it goes really slow, it takes something like 3-5 minutes, but it only takes 2-3 seconds without. (Gets about 4000 records back).

Example:

The Query:

```
 query GetAllItems {
    getAllItems {
      id
      name
      isInCart @client <-- This one is the problem
    }
  }
```

I need this field inside "Items", to mark the items inside the cart.

Resolver:

```
resolvers: {
  Item: {
   isInCart: () => false;
  }
}
```

Any idea why the query gets really slow with the @client directive? Or how i can work around this?

Let me know if there is needed for more informations.

Comment: why? this is a derived data ... component can query both items (paginated) and cart - simple function in render will do the same

Comment: @xadm Because, if i use function in render, it will rerender all items when one item is changed. That will cause performance issue. But if you have an example of a way to skip this issue, i would be glad to use it :)

Comment: using pagination or virtualized list resolves most performance problems